# Upgraded Nexus OSS from 2.14 to 3.2 tells me it's incompatible

Tags: nexus, sonatype

When attempting to pull the contents of my Nexus 2.14 instance into my new Nexus 3 instance, I get the following error.

> Incompatible versions: nexus/OSS/2.14.3-02 to nexus/OSS/3.2.0-01

What do I have to do to upgrade to 3.2? Install Nexus 3.1 then upgrade to 3.2? Why have the category Upgrade if I can't use it?

Answer (score 1):

https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/upgrading.html

2.14.1 -> 3.1

2.14.2 -> 3.2

2.14.3 -> 3.2.1

Looks like I'm a minor version off somewhere.

Comment: Yes, you need to use 3.2.1 to upgrade